# Safari can't open video served on localhost through Laravel

Tags: laravel, safari, mp4

This is my HTML:

```
<video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted poster="">
    <source src="{{ asset('media/video/video.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video should autoplay when visiting the website, and it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. But not Safari. This problem only occurs when visiting the video through localhost. Opening the video as a normal file in Safari, straight from my disk, plays it fine.

This makes me think this problem occurs somewhere in Laravel failing to serve the MP4 for Safari through localhost.

Is this a known issue, and if so, how to solve it? I am using Laravel v9.

**Edit:**

So, in Safari:

- http://localhost:8000/path/to/video.mp4 -> fails
- `<source src="{{ asset('/path/to/video.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">` (code) -> fails
- file://mysites/path/to/video.mp4 -> works

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was using the command `php artisan serve` to test my website. This opens a PHP/Laravel development server. But this server is poorly configured and cannot handle the 'Range Bytes' Safari requires to stream MP4.

Just place your Laravel project on a local Apache server and test it through there.